# nodemon - running server and recompiling scss in same process

Tags: npm, nodemon, node-sass

I have installed node-sass and have set it up to recompile every time that the .scss source is changed.

Separately I use nodemon to look for changes in my files and restart the server.

My package.json script look like this:

```
"watch": "nodemon ./bin/www",
"watch-css": "node-sass -w scss -o public/css"
```

This works fine, however it requires me to keep two terminals open at all times.

Is there any way to tell nodemon to run/restart the server, and in the special case where an scss file is changed, to recompile AND restart?

Comment: You can try out with `Pm2` as it is a process manager for Node.JS applications with a built-in load balancer. check the below link that might be helpful to you.

https://npmcompare.com/compare/forever,nodemon,pm2,strong-pm

Answer (score 0):

```
"watch": "npm run watch-code & npm run watch-css",
"watch-code": "nodemon ./bin/www",
"watch-css": "node-sass -w scss -o public/css"
```

should do the trick I believe.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The approach suggested by Remy doesn't work on Windows, I think

A cross-platform solution could be use the package [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all), which can be easely installed using `npm install --save-dev npm-run-all`

Then, you need to modify your `package.json`

```
"watch-app": "nodemon ./bin/www",
"watch-css": "node-sass -w scss -o public/css"
"watch": "npm-run-all --parallel watch-app watch-css"
```

So, you'll get the same behavior on Windows and UNIX platforms.

Ultimately it would be the same behavior suggested by Remy, which is to run both scripts in parallel